# Emacs + SLIME + SBCL (Windows)

Tags: windows, emacs, lisp, sbcl, slime

I'm attempting to get Emacs, Slime and SBCL to work together on a Windows 7 machine. I use Linux typically, so I'm not experienced with the process. The problem is that I get this error when I attempt to start SLIME: `Searching for program: permission denied, sbcl`

Here's my Emacs 24 *init.el*:

```
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
(setq slime-auto-connect 'ask)

(defun my-slime-setup ()

 (require 'slime)

  (slime-setup))

(defvar my--slime-setup-done nil)
(defun my-slime-setup-once ()
  (unless my--slime-setup-done
    (my-slime-setup)
    (setq my--slime-setup-done t)))
(defadvice lisp-mode (before my-slime-setup-once activate)
  (my-slime-setup-once))
```

My SBCL path is `C:\Program Files\Steel Bank Common Lisp\1.2.7\sbcl` if that makes any difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On mine I had to do this to get it working on Windows:

```
(setq slime-lisp-implementations '((sbcl ("C:\\Program Files\\Steel Bank Common Lisp\\1.2.8\\sbcl.exe" "--core" "C:\\Program Files\\Steel Bank Common Lisp\\1.2.8\\sbcl.core"))))
```